# My laptop behaves strange after suspend

Tags: linux, power, arch-linux, suspend

When waking my laptop from suspend, it behaves very strange - the CPU quickly gets hot and the battery drains insanely fast. Looking into powertop, there is a process called 'rtc_timer_do_work' that wakes up often and uses 10 Watts. Heres what powertop gives me:

```
Power est.     Usage         Events/s     Category       Description
10.44 W         51.0 ms/s     209.7       kWork          rtc_timer_do_work
```

After a reboot that problem is gone, but I don't want to reboot after suspending, then suspend makes no sense at all.

Short description of my system:

- ASUS PRO62J
- i7 Q720
- 8G RAM
- Nvidia 240M
- Arch Linux w/ 3.7 linux-ck-nahelem Kernel

I've tried different kernels(default, ck, optimized ck from repository) and a multitude of kernel options(I've compiled the kernel like 20 times) but nothing has worked so far and when searching for the processes name nothing really helping pops up.

Is there any way to return this process to its normal state(a usage of several mWatts, not Watts)?

Comment: Have you only looked into 3.7-kernels or earlier versions, too? Could you test any other Linux distro, e.g. from a USB pen drive (there should be some, which support suspend from a pen drive)? Anyway, this looks like worth of being posted on the Linux kernel mailing list ...